# Desandro's Masonry - Keep 1 large block centralized and wrap the other items around it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

When arranging items with Masonry, is it possible to have 1 item that is twice the width of other items at a fixed position in the second row. Even when sorting the items, this big item should always stay at that position. I managed to do this for the top left spot, but not for a spot in the middle of the grid. Does masonry support this?

Regards